# multiple pages get navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to know the best way to 'get' the index `.nav` and `.footer` and other elements that always stay on the page and then copy them to my subpages.

I'm trying to avoid copying and pasting these elements into the HTML subpages.

Comment: Why are looking for jQuery solution for this? Why don't you use user controls or common view?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish here? If you want to create the same layout across multiple pages, creating a template file and loading that would be a lot easier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery'a `load()` function.

You can put this on any page you want the nav or footer to duplicate to:

```
$("#nav") // select nav element on current page
    .load("index.html #nav > *"); // grab contents of nav from index page
```

Of course, the best way will still be to either put the nav in a file alone and use PHP to include it on the page or just copy and paste them, in case you have a smaller site.

Answer (score 1):

Use a server side language (PHP, Ruby, etc.) and split them out into "includes".

Or alternatively use some kind of build systme that allows you to "include" snippets and then compile the files to completed html pages before publishing. Adobe Dreamweaver's Templates and Library features are an example of this, but you could do it with open source tools like Rake, Phing and Ant as well.

Comment: I would encourage `includes` via PHP as well. It's worked great for my site so far.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net use `MasterPage`s:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

PHP use `include`s:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Or you can `jQuery.load()` the sections of a `template.html` into each page:

http://api.jquery.com/load/